# Pandas cutting off values of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove the ".0" from all values in a column in a dataframe.

attached is my structure

```
data = {'Date':['2020-02-05 12:54:49.0', '2021-02-06 16:27:09.0', '2022-02-07 16:57:15.0'],'User':[28,34,29]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.0` is the microsecond part, it is represented by `%f`. You can convert the column to datetime type and convert the datetime type back to string format without `%f`

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

```
print(df)

                  Date  User
0  2020-02-05 12:54:49    28
1  2021-02-06 16:27:09    34
2  2022-02-07 16:57:15    29
```

If you just want to remove `.0` and leave `.123` etc. You can use `.str.rstrip`

```py
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.rstrip('.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].str.replace("\.0$", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                  Date  User
0  2020-02-05 12:54:49    28
1  2021-02-06 16:27:09    34
2  2022-02-07 16:57:15    29
```

The pattern ".0$" will only match a dot (`.`) followed by `0` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just jettison 2 last characters, that is

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Date':['2020-02-05 12:54:49.0', '2021-02-06 16:27:09.0', '2022-02-07 16:57:15.0'],'User':[28,34,29]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = df.Date.str[:-2]
print(df)
```

output

```
                  Date  User
0  2020-02-05 12:54:49    28
1  2021-02-06 16:27:09    34
2  2022-02-07 16:57:15    29
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do the job involves thinking about what you want to do with the data *after* you remove the trailing milliseconds from the 'Date' column.

#### Do you need to do **a lot** of date manipulation later?

If that's your case, you can simply use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) like this.

Since *all* the dates end with ".0", when you convert the date to a string, the milliseconds part will be removed:

```py
>>> df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
>>> print(df.Date)
0   2020-02-05 12:54:49
1   2021-02-06 16:27:09
2   2022-02-07 16:57:15
>>> print(df.Date.dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```

**When** it is a good idea to do this? when you have to do a lot of date manipulations.

If the date in your dataframe is a string, when you do something like  `df.Date > "2021-01-01"`, it will trigger a conversion from string to date for *every* row (and it won't be cached).

#### I just need to store the string to display somewhere else

Case 1: **IF you are sure** all dates end with '.0', you can just strip the last 2 characters from the string:

```py
df.Date = df.Date.apply(lambda x: x[:-2])
```

This is *very* quick. But if the milliseconds part has more than one character it will fail ('2021-01-01 01:02:03.0456' -> '2021-01-01 01:02:03.**04**'

Case 2: Split the string after the dot (there are no dots in the middle of dates).

Just like this:

```
df.Date =  df.Date.apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
```